# What is the difference between build configuration language and language in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When setting up a new project in Android Studio with the Empty Views Activity, it gives the option of both a language and build configuration language.
I was wondering what the actual difference between them is.

I'm trying to build the app in Java.

Comment: As a follow up suggestion to my answer, take a look into Kotlin. The Android world is transitioning from a Java/Groovy pair for application language and configuration script language to writting everything in Kotlin. You can pretty much mix and match those options but, if your starting fresh, it's easier to learn only one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `language` option is for you to set the language in which you want to write your Android application. If you want to write it in Java, that's the place to select that option.

However, Android project's use a build tool called Gradle. This tool uses configuration scripts that can be written in different languages than your main project. So, the `build configuration language` is the place for you to configure in which language you want to write these build scripts.

If you're just starting, don't worry to much about those build scripts. The Android Studio will generate almost everything you need until you get in a more advanced setup.